# Spark view engine performance with prefix in MVC 2 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

I use spark view engine in my MVC 2 project. By default, Spark tags are unqualified, without prefix. My question is: Do I gain performance when put prefix in my web.config file? Put differently, whether spark files compile faster with prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation will not be any faster or slower with the prefix.

Spark not only outputs HTML, but is equally capable of outputting valid XML, and in the latter case, you very often need to qualify your tags to maintain valid XML.

None of this will effect compilation time. It is recommended however, regardless of this, that you [precompile](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/precompiling) your views for production anyway to improve performance.